# List<T> not deserialize xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a xml and for deserialize it I created a class with `List<Order>` type. But when i try to deserialize it below code is not able to deserialize the XML and i am not getting `List<Order>` value.

I am providing the code i have tried, XML and Class for XML.

**Code**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ECFindOrderResponse.Envelope));    
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(str))
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        ECFindOrderResponse.Envelope result = (ECFindOrderResponse.Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        if (result != null && result.Body != null)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

**My expected XML as a response that i want to deserialize**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <m:FindOrderResponse xmlns:m="http://www.courier.com/schemas/">
         <Orders>
            <Order OrderID="9653653" OrderNumber="9653653" Auth="19204071" Service="NAT-Other" AmountCharged="96.39" PodName="Tina Sample" PodDateTime="10/8/2016 10:19:00 AM" OrderDate="10/8/2016">
               <Stops>
                  <Stop Sequence="1" Name="United Airlines" Address="AWB#016-9672-4071" City="LOUISVILLE" State="KY" Zip="40213" DispatchZone="40213" />
                  <Stop Sequence="2" Name="Tina Sample" Address="6300 Aurora Ave" City="Charlestown" State="IN" Zip="47111" DispatchZone="47111" />
               </Stops>
            </Order>
            <Order OrderID="9653653" OrderNumber="9653653" Auth="19204071" Service="NAT-Other" AmountCharged="96.39" PodName="Tina Sample" PodDateTime="10/8/2016 10:19:00 AM" OrderDate="10/8/2016">
               <Stops>
                  <Stop Sequence="1" Name="United Airlines" Address="AWB#016-9672-4071" City="LOUISVILLE" State="KY" Zip="40213" DispatchZone="40213" />
                  <Stop Sequence="2" Name="Tina Sample" Address="6300 Aurora Ave" City="Charlestown" State="IN" Zip="47111" DispatchZone="47111" />
               </Stops>
            </Order>
         </Orders>
      </m:FindOrderResponse>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

**C# Class file**

```
public  class ECFindOrderResponse
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Stop")]
    public class Stop
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Sequence")]
        public string Sequence { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Zip")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DispatchZone")]
        public string DispatchZone { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Stops")]
    public class Stops
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Stop")]
        public List<Stop> Stop { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Order")]
    public class Order
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Stops")]
        public Stops Stops { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OrderID")]
        public string OrderID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OrderNumber")]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Auth")]
        public string Auth { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Service")]
        public string Service { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "AmountCharged")]
        public string AmountCharged { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PodName")]
        public string PodName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PodDateTime")]
        public string PodDateTime { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OrderDate")]
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Orders")]
    public class Orders
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Order")]
        public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FindOrderResponse", Namespace = "http://www.courier.com/schemas/")]
    public class FindOrderResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Orders")]
        public Orders Orders { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "m", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string M { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FindOrderResponse", Namespace = "http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/")]
        public FindOrderResponse FindOrderResponse { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAP { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not getting deserialize?

Comment: `ECFindOrderResponse` does not contain any properties or fields, so there is nothing to deserialize. You've declared some nested classes, but that is quite different.

Comment: @ReyanChougle thanks, when i pass the xml as a string that will be my expected response. This is return only Envelope and Body value but List<Order> i get nothing

Comment: @JohnWu thanks but if you view i have created a nested class for  Orders and in  Orders i have created a List<Order>

Comment: Just creating the nested class does nothing. You must have a  ***property*** that is a `List<Order>`.

Comment: @JohnWu can you please describe how can i do `property that is a List<Order>` for my above xml

Comment: See Daniel's answer, in which there is a public property named `Orders` of type `List<Order>`. That is what I am referring to. A nested class by itself just declares a type within the namespace of the class; it doesn't define any instance or property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FindOrderResponse", Namespace = "http://www.courier.com/schemas/")]
public class FindOrderResponse
{
    [XmlArray("Orders")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Order")]
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "m", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string M { get; set; }
}
```

The important parts here are the `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes which were missing in your code.

Comment: (edited previous) - ah, I see; you're right that the explicit `[XmlElement(ElementName = "Orders")]` is a problem, but: the `[XmlArray]` / `[XmlArrayItem]` shown here are IIRC implicit and can be omitted, as long as the `[XmlElement]` is removed

Comment: @Daniel I am getting Orders count=0 after your suggested changed

Comment: @A.Goutam you could try making the `Namespace=""` explicit? i.e. `[XmlArray("Orders", Namespace = "")]`, `[XmlArrayItem("Order", Namespace = "")]` - in general though, Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes is much easier (then tidy it up); the IDE suggests: 
 `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Namespace = "")]`
    `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Order", IsNullable = false)]` (it is verbose sometimes)